# Ubuntu Stuck on Loading Screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb

I prepared a Bootable USB drive (64GB) to install Ubuntu, but then I accidentally formatted my hard disk (with windows 10 on it) so I wanted to try to restore that, but after few commands in the terminal I got error "No more space left on device" or something like "No more space on disk" and I dont had another USB to temporally install Ubuntu to free up space on because I wanted to restore the hard drive, but as I came back to the laptop, The other day, The Ubuntu loading screen got stuck at loading, and is loading forever, not matter if I started Ubuntu as live or the setup installer. Does the "No more space on disk is somehow connected to that problem, and does someone knows how to fix that problem of Ubuntu stuck at loading?
Few Erorrs that popped out in startup:

```
Start Up Errors: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e 
MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e nouveau 0000:01:00.0: 
DRM: failed to create kernel channel, -22
```

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu on the USB drive (i.e. went through the installer and selected the USB drive)? If you just wrote the ISO image, then it should be read-only, unless you explicitly selected the persistent storage option in the programme you created it with.

Comment: No, I just downloaded the ISO image and than booted without selecting space for Ubuntu, can you send me a tutorial on how to do it? And if I will choose a persistent storage then the loading problem should be gone?

Comment: What I meant is that the USB drive couldn't be full since it's read-only when created by normal means. How did you try to fix your hard drive after you formatted it?

Comment: I couldn't - right after I got in to Ubuntu live I tried this command in the terminal: apt-get install testdisk and it gave me that error:"No more space on disk".

Comment: GParted Live CD/USB (https://gparted.sourceforge.io/livecd.php) is a much more suitable distro for recovery. It has most software you need for that, including testdisk.